# Docker connect to mocked service on host port

Tags: docker, soapui

I am using docker to run my web app on my local machine and I have created mocked web service using SoapUI on host machine.

The mocked service is accessible through localhost:8099 and IP 127.0.0.1:8099 (using telnet), I am however unable to access it from running docker container.

I have read some articles about discovering host IP address through

```
ip addr show docker0
```

with results:

```
5: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:e3:36:43:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:e3ff:fe36:435b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

When I tried to ping IP `172.17.0.1` from docker container I am getting responses just OK, but when trying to call the mocked web service from my web app I get responses `No route to host`.

I have also tried to modify iptables using `iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT` but with no success.

Is there any other setting that I am missing?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks, shimon

Comment: Which OS are you using? If Linux, try the actual ip address of the host machine? I assume it's Linux based on `docker0`. The ip address you are getting is the internal ip of the container assigned by Docker for Docker networking and link, which is not accessible from outside the host.

Comment: What machine are you running the `ip addr...` command on?

Comment: @JHarris - I run the `ip addr..` command on my host machine (it's ubuntu).

Comment: @techtabu - I havev tried to use the actual IP of host machine, but I am getting the same response `No route to host` :(

Answer (score 0):

If I have read your question right your local and host machines are not the same machine. In which case you won't be able to (unless you have set a tunnel up on localhost:8099) be able to access your mocker service on the host machine using localhost as it will resolve to your local ip (on your local machine).

What you need to do is make sure both machines can talk to each other and use the host machines IP instead of localhost.

Comment: Hi, my host machine is Ubuntu, and it runs the docker container (physicaly they run on one machine - my laptop).

Comment: what is the result from docker ps?

EDIT: you can also get the ip address of the docker container by using `docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' <container id>` this might help you debug the situation.

Comment: the result is `172.17.0.3` - however, I a don't know how to use this to debug the problem

Comment: my concern is that perhaps you haven't exposed the port on your container - hence I was curious to see the output from `docker ps`